# How to play PhoneGap Video

Tags: cordova

I am new to PhoneGap development (Android). For playing a video from SD Card/online which would be the best option. Does anyone get this working?

I have tried many options and nothing seems to work... But I think -playing video - should be one of the common scenario & if any one have across this - pls send me a working sample...

Answer (score 0):

for playing video files from your device, you can use the videoplayer plugin (https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer). however for purpose of streaming youtube videos, I personally prefer the combination of using webintents for android along with the youtube api, because that allows playing youtube video in full screen straight from app . if you are using the video player plugin, it will open the native youtube app if you try to play a youtube video. It all depends upon ur requirement though.

Comment: I have tried this as well as - including - http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js. Nothing seems to work. Can u pls send me the working sample.